# Conflict in PATH variable between R and Python

Tags: python, r, bash, unix

I have the following in my `.bash_profile`.

```
# Setting PATH for R 4.2.1 
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
# Setting PATH for Python 3.8
PATH="/Users/RhaenyraTargaryen/opt/miniconda3/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

This allows me to load the correct version of python in the `miniconda3/bin` folder, which is necessary. However, now instead of `R` loading from the `Resources/bin` folder, it's also being loaded from `miniconda3/bin` and causing errors, since this version doesn't have all the libraries installed. How do I make it so the `python` is loaded from one path and `R` from the other, without confusion between the paths in my `.bash_profile`? I haven't been able to find any blogs or tutorials that address this issue, so any advice here is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Keep the `R` path before the `miniconda` path:  `PATH="${PATH}:/Users/RhaenyraTargaryen/opt/miniconda3/bin"`.

Comment: Hmm, when I switch `PATH="/Users/RhaenyraTargaryen/opt/miniconda3/bin:${PATH}"` to `PATH="${PATH}:/Users/RhaenyraTargaryen/opt/miniconda3/bin"`, I receive `zsh: killed     python3`. Any thought as to why this might be?

Comment: Ah, I had another bad python path that was put ahead of the good one when I switched the order of the paths as you suggested. What you @MauriceMeyer suggest works great and fixed the problem! Thank you so much!! :)

Comment: You shouldn't need to add those bins when running everything, consider using them just when you're loading python or R. You can create an alternate "executable" (shell script) that modifies the `PATH` for just running R, such as `PATH="/Users/.../bin:${PATH}" R "$@"` (no newline), and its path does not need to be seen by other apps (such as your python).

Comment: This is also a good suggestion @r2evans! I will use this in the future :)

Comment: Try to move the first 3 lines below the last 3 lines.